# SQLite Java : Connect to encrypted database

Tags: java, sqlite

Suppose I have a db file called `mydb.db` and it is encrypted. How can I connect to it and execute query in Java ?

This is what I have done

```
    try {
        // db parameters
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("key", "XohImNooBHFR0OVvjcYpJ3NgPQ1qq73WKhHvch0VQtg=");

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + DB_FILE;
        // create a connection to the database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);

        System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

.
.
.

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

but i got this error when trying to prepare the statement

`[SQLITE_NOTADB]  File opened that is not a database file (file is encrypted or is not a database)`

I'm using sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-M1.jar

Comment: How is the database encrypted?

Comment: I guess it is SQLCipher and I can open the database using that database type in SQLiteStudio. In Java, I can only query if the database is the normal SQLite3

Comment: Some quick googling found [this](https://github.com/decamp/sqlcipher-jdbc) jdbc driver. Might be a dead project though since it hasn't had a commit in years.

Comment: yea i follow that one and tried to make my own jar.. But got error everywhere lolz.. After sometime, I have decided to create a new plain sqlite3 db file and copy tables from `mydb.db` to that file using sqlitestudio

Comment: but still hope there's a way to open sqlcipher db directly in java though